# Spring batch : MySQL Paging

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-batch

I want send 600 000 000 message in Kafka topic from large table MySQL.
I want use Spring Batch for this usage but it use query type:

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM t1 LIMIT offset, size;
```

Generated in spring-batch/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/support/MySQLPagingQueryProvider.java :

```
public String generateJumpToItemQuery(int itemIndex, int pageSize) {
    int page = itemIndex / pageSize;
    int offset = (page * pageSize) - 1;

    offset = offset<0 ? 0 : offset;

    String limitClause = new StringBuilder().append("LIMIT ").append(offset).append(", 1").toString();

    return SqlPagingQueryUtils.generateLimitJumpToQuery(this, limitClause);

}
```

This solution is very slow because `LIMIT offset, size` involves re-reading at each iteration . I prefert :

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM t1 WHERE primary > last_primary_lot LIMIT size;
```

It's possible ?

Comment: How about using normal JdbcTemplate  with your query and in your rowmapper's mapRow post to kafka?

Comment: @NawnitSen a row mapper is meant to map database rows to domain objects. So posting messages to kafka in it would make it do two things at the same time, which goes against the well known principle of making one thing do one thing and do it well. @cedricROCHART `This solution is very slow`: Can you give some numbers? What would you qualify as fast, what are your expectations?

Comment: It is in reflection for the choice of technology. I was watching how the tool worked. I have tables of several hundred million rows and in another context with a shell processing based on a limits / offsets. The more I advance, the slower my treatment. On the seek method by limiting the primary keys my processing remains very fast from start to finish.